# what was it help for compiler when used @class-@interface pair?

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

```
@class  GSValue;
@interface GSValue : NSObject   // Help the compiler
@end
@class  GSNonretainedObjectValue;
@interface GSNonretainedObjectValue : NSObject  // Help the compiler
@end
```

the above code from NSValue.m . i google and giving me some info, it indicate that  @class(not accompanying with @interface) used for class forward declaration between two classes,but only declared as a pointer of the class. my question is why "@class GSValue;" immediately followed by "@interface GSValue:NSObject",what's the meaning?

Comment: I do not think that this has any meaning at all, although it is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, but i think in this case it's forward declaration + declaration, that `GSValue`and other classes are subclasses of `NSObject`. So, compiler won't give a warning when you write `[GSValue class]`. It's not actually "help", it's just to get rid of warnings.

Though, if this is the case then I don't know why they use forward declaration with `@interface`, cause it works just the same without `@class` directive.

I see it that way.

They used forward declaration in the first place. Then they noticed that compiler gives warnings `Receiver 'GSValue' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist`, so they added `@interface` sections, but forgot or didn't bother to delete former `@class` directives.

Comment: hi @Alexander N.
i 'm using objective-c on GNUSTEP. i delete the whole "@interface" and leaving "@class". it's no warning come out of compiler.

Comment: Well, that's a shame. There _should_ be a warning, 'cause compiler does not know if an undeclared class has any methods (like `class`).